# Bash Regex parsing USB name within quotes from blkid

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to grab the USB name (MYUSB) from the `blkid` command. Currently, I have the following output. I want to grab the name of the USB that starts with `LABEL`. so the output would just be `MYUSB`. How can i achieve this?

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="88dd2cc5-0a4f-4477-b678-159613aaf920" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="ggxkwK-DZfA-DnTF-dWbn-msx6-egfo-GuGIuS" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg_baldy1-lv_root: UUID="76ab63ba-e8c4-4040-9533-5c8562f739d4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg_baldy1-lv_swap: UUID="462a170b-5e09-4b98-98ce-09e0a24009ab" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg_baldy1-lv_home: UUID="c38c0b9a-1049-4e9f-8800-d68d2e450929" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MYUSB" UUID="BF05-9FC6" TYPE="vfat"
```

Comment: Which part of the line is the important part for figuring out if you have the correct one?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What do you mean? `/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MYUSB" UUID="BF05-9FC6" TYPE="vfat"` This is the line i am interested in.

Comment: `blkid` appears to have [several formatting options](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) to only show the parts you want without having to parse the defaut output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `blkid | grep -o -P '(?<=LABEL=")([^"]*)'`

This should pipe the output of `blkid` into grep which returns only the part of the string that matches the regular expression.

It should be noted that if more than one label happens to be present in the output of `blkid`, this will output all labels, each on a new line. Therefore to only get the last label, use:

`blkid | grep -o -P '(?<=LABEL=")([^"]*)' | tail -1`

Regex explanation:

- `(?<=LABEL=")` - Asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is `LABEL="`.
- `([^"]*)` - Matches and captures zero or more characters that aren't `"` (the part in-between the quotation marks).

Comment: Thank you for that, what if i want to only get the last label name (last USB attached)? How can i do this?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour add `| tail -1`

Comment: Oh one last thing, is there a man page for the wrap around `'(?<=LABEL=")([^"]*)'`?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour You want documentation for the regex lookbehind? If so, you can find a tutorial page [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).